# PostgreSQL creating timestamp ranges

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

In PostgreSQL 11, I am trying to get a weekend time range. From 17:00 Friday to Sunday 17:00.

So far I am able to get a working day by doing

```
select * from generate_series(date '2021-01-01',date '2021-12-31',interval '1' day) as t(dt) where extract (dow from dt) between 1 and 5;
```

However, I am have trouble creating 2 columns from start (17:00 Friday) to finish (17:00 Sunday).

Expected output should be something like this:

```
start                  stop
2022-10-07 17:00    2022-10-09 17:00
2022-10-14 17:00    2022-10-16 17:00
2022-10-21 17:00    2022-10-23 17:00
```

Comment: See my answer for a first attempt. It would be helpful if you provided a sample of expected output.

Comment: 1) It is important to be consistent in your question. Your query example is `date '2021-01-01',date '2021-12-31'` but your output example is for the year `2022`. 2) See update to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a series of all hours between `17:00` on Friday and `17:00` on Sunday.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    generate_series(timestamp '2021-01-01', timestamp '2021-12-31', interval '1' hour) AS t (dt)
WHERE
    extract(dow FROM dt) IN (5, 6, 0)
    AND CASE WHEN extract(dow FROM dt) = 5 THEN
        extract(hour FROM dt) >= 17
    WHEN extract(dow FROM dt) = 0 THEN
        extract(hour FROM dt) <= 17
    ELSE
        extract(hour FROM dt) IS NOT NULL
    END;
```

**UPDATE**

Get two timestamps that represent start and stop of each period `Friday 17:00` to `Sunday 17:00` over a range of dates.

```
SELECT
    dt + '17:00'::time as start, (dt + '17:00'::time) + '2 days'::interval as stop
FROM
    generate_series(date '2022-01-01', date '2022-12-31', interval '1' day) AS t (dt)
WHERE
    extract(dow FROM dt) = 5
;


   start          |          stop           
-------------------------+-------------------------
 01/07/2022 17:00:00 PST | 01/09/2022 17:00:00 PST
 01/14/2022 17:00:00 PST | 01/16/2022 17:00:00 PST
 01/21/2022 17:00:00 PST | 01/23/2022 17:00:00 PST
 01/28/2022 17:00:00 PST | 01/30/2022 17:00:00 PST
 02/04/2022 17:00:00 PST | 02/06/2022 17:00:00 PST
 02/11/2022 17:00:00 PST | 02/13/2022 17:00:00 PST
 02/18/2022 17:00:00 PST | 02/20/2022 17:00:00 PST
 02/25/2022 17:00:00 PST | 02/27/2022 17:00:00 PST
 03/04/2022 17:00:00 PST | 03/06/2022 17:00:00 PST
 03/11/2022 17:00:00 PST | 03/13/2022 17:00:00 PDT
 03/18/2022 17:00:00 PDT | 03/20/2022 17:00:00 PDT
 03/25/2022 17:00:00 PDT | 03/27/2022 17:00:00 PDT
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--timestamptz type.

    SELECT
        (day + interval '17:30') AS start,
        (day + interval '17:30' + interval '2 days') AS
    END
    FROM
        generate_series(date '2022-10-01', date '2022-12-31', interval '1' day) _ (day)
    WHERE
        EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM day) = 5;

--timestamp type. 

    SELECT
        (day + interval '17:30')::timestamp AS start,
        (day + interval '17:30' + interval '2 days')::timestamp AS
    END
    FROM
        generate_series(date '2022-10-01', date '2022-12-31', interval '1' day) _ (day)
    WHERE
        EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM day) = 5;
```

I do checked the calendar, it works.